# Django: exists() using queryset cache

Tags: django, django-queryset

Does django's `QuerySet.exists()` method use the queryset's cache if called twice?
For example

```py
# this makes a call to db
queryset.exists()
# > true

# does it make a call to the db or reuse some cached result?
queryset.exists()
# > true
```

I know that `len(queryset)` won't make a call to the db if it has previously been evaluated. Is it the same with `exists`?

Comment: Yes, it forces reevaluation. If you are planning to use `queryset` however, you can use `if queryset` (or `bool(queryset)`), this will cache the results, such that you can then also enumerate over these.

Comment: Yes, if you just want to see if it exists, using ```exists``` is the right way. as said [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.exists()` twice, it will make *two* queries, the queryset will *not* cache the outcome of the `.exists()` call.

If you however plan to enumerate over the queryset, you can check the truthiness of the queryset with:

```
if queryset:
    # not empty
    pass
else:
    # empty
    pass
```

This will make a query and load the records into the cache of the queryset, so later enumerating over the queryset, applying `len(…)`, etc. will not trigger a new query.

This however should be avoided if you are only interested to check if an item exists, for the same reason you should use [**`.count()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count) over `len(…)` if you are only interested in the number of records: by using `len(…)` you load the *records* into memory, which is more expensive than making a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query.

Comment: what about evaluating the query `list(queryset)` then calling `.exists()`. Will exists make a call to db or used the cached result of the evaluation?

Comment: @MartinFaucheux: It will check if the result cache is not empty, so it will not make an extra query: https://github.com/django/django/blob/d35ce682e31ea4a86c2079c60721fae171f03d7c/django/db/models/query.py#L1004